# SharePoint 2013 - Failed to install the application content files. An exception of type System.Xml.XmlException was thrown

Tags: 2013

While running the 'PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures' on my web server for the December 2018 CU I ran into the following error.

> Failed to install the application content files. An exception of type System.Xml.XmlException was thrown. Configuration of SharePoint Products Failed. Configuration must be performed before you use SharePoint Products.

Have no clue on how to read the logs or what the errors mean. Have not found a solution online, so hope someone here can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below:

```
stsadm -o setproperty -pn command-line-upgrade-running -pv No

Psconfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -wait -force
```